# Can I decrypt a partition in Ubuntu which is encrypted using BitLocker (utility of Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I encrypted a 200GB partition of HDD in Windows 7 using [BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/bitlocker).  I removed Windows 7 from the PC and installed Ubuntu.  Now I can't see the partition which was encrypted from Ubuntu.

**Question:** Is there any way to access or decrypt this partition in Ubuntu?

By the way, I know the key which is used in encryption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux) contains a discussion of accessing bitlocker encrypted volumes in Linux. In summary, experimental tools exist, but it is unconfirmed if they work or not. It does not appear that there is an easy way of doing this.