# I Secured my USB using bitlocker on a windows 7 pc but now i cant see it in ubuntu

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I decrypt a partition in Ubuntu which is encrypted using BitLocker (utility of Windows 7)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187329/can-i-decrypt-a-partition-in-ubuntu-which-is-encrypted-using-bitlocker-utility)

How can i read/write to my USB-drive, that is locked using bitlocker in ubuntu? (12.04.1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I decrypt a partition in Ubuntu which is encrypted using BitLocker (utility of Windows 7)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187329/can-i-decrypt-a-partition-in-ubuntu-which-is-encrypted-using-bitlocker-utility). See also: http://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux

Comment: How is this a duplicate from http://askubuntu.com/questions/187329/can-i-decrypt-a-partition-in-ubuntu-which-is-encrypted-using-bitlocker-utility he is talking about partitions, i am talking about USB... or are the actions the same?

Comment: BitLocker is the proprietary Windows encryption. In order to read it you need a decryption soft. These are linked to above - procedures are the same. It would only marginally be on topic for AU anyway. Nevertheless we do hope you can access your files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitlocker is proprietary and only designed for Windows. You need to remove the encryption in Windows in order to use the USB stick in Linux.

There is an experimental tool to access bitlocker encrypted folders in Linux called [dislocker](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/download/). However, there is no guarantee it will work.