# Remove bitlocker encryption using ubuntu

Tags: encryption

I can access the drive using dislocker but I want to remove the encryption.
I have migrated from Windows 10 to ubuntu 14.04 so I can't remove it using Windows.

Comment: Do you want to just overwrite everything, no file recovery or decryption?

Comment: @Xen2050 - I want to remove the encryption. The files should not be removed.

Comment: Ok, so trying to decrypt BitLocker using only Ubuntu... this question has been asked before, and there doesn't appear to be a clear answer. See http://askubuntu.com/a/199222/129271 that suggests trying [Dislocker](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/) Or this Q is a better match: http://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I decrypt a partition in Ubuntu which is encrypted using BitLocker (utility of Windows 7)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187329/can-i-decrypt-a-partition-in-ubuntu-which-is-encrypted-using-bitlocker-utility)

Comment: Found a **Better duplicate Q: http://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?rq=1 .** , but it says I can't vote again if I retract this vote...

Comment: @Xen2050 - I should have clearly specified this before. I want to remove the decryption. I can already access the drives using dislocker. I want to decrypt my drive so that i don't have to use dislocker tool every time I need to access my drive. Kind of like turning off bitlocker permanently.

Answer (score 2):

> > I want to remove the decryption... I want to decrypt my drive so that i don't have to use dislocker tool every time I need to access my drive. Kind of like turning off bitlocker permanently.

That's similar to re-formatting any drive with a new filesystem, but to keep the files there are a few more steps:

1. Copy the files somewhere else (in this case using Dislocker). This is an excellent opportunity to make a backup copy too.
2. Format the partition with a filesystem of your choice (ex. using `mkfs.ext3`, etc). If you still wanted encryption, LUKS works well for linux partitions, or there are other options too for folder/files,  [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption) has a good overview.
3. Copy the files back onto the partition.

I don't think any in-place Bitlocker encryption removal tool exists that could do it all at once, and it would have a high risk of data loss should something go wrong anyway.

Comment: So basically, no way to do it. Thanx anyway. Is there any cross platform encryptor?

Comment: TrueCrypt used to be THE one. The [ArchWiki Encryption Comparison table](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption#Comparison_table) has a compatibility with Win/Mac/FreeBSD section, it looks like programs TrueCrypt, FreeOTFE & CrossCrypt are abandoned, but there are several TrueCrypt successors (LUKS's cryptsetup supports truecrypt) and DOXBOX is now called " LibreCrypt: Transparent on-the-fly disk encryption for Windows. LUKS compatible"